# How Dangerous is Jurassic Park/World?

Tags: jurassic-park, kill-count, jurassic-world

So we know that [all four Jurassic movies take place in the same world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133924/are-all-four-of-the-jurassic-park-films-canon).

We also know that the theme parks both exist on the same island, but that The Lost World was on a different one.

Of course, it is relatively easy to see that the park had a bloody history - there were numerous deaths and injuries at Jurassic Park, and the related animals caused havoc among other groups.

That said, has this number been quantified?  Is there any indication how many people have actually been killed or injured across the Jurassic Park/World franchise?

Comment: *"I think the important thing is that although tragedies occurred at the first two parks, **Jurassic World 2**'s safety procedures are second to none and we're now the first park in history to be guaranteed [100% mistak-free."*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7trn91xkJ0w)

Comment: till life finds a way!

Comment: "Welcome to Itchy and Scratchy Land, where nothing could possibli go wrong. Uh, *possibly* go wrong. Huh, that's the first thing that's ever gone wrong."

Comment: @Valorum - Was the typo in "mistake" intentional?  (If so, kudos: because a mistake in the spelling of "mistake-free" is awesome.)

Comment: @Ghotir - That's the first mistake that's ever happened at Jurassic World 2.

Comment: Nedry’s control program had zarro boogs.

Comment: @Valorum - spared **no expense**!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Body Count = **75(ish)** depending on how you choose to count the boat crews.

**Jurassic Park**
Surprisingly non-bloody. There were only a few guests and most of the park's staff had already left. In the film, the death count was a measly **5.** If you're a book fan, you can add an extra 1, with John Hammond getting et.

**The Lost World: Jurassic Park**
A bit more exciting, largely due to the presence of a clueless (and apparently delicious) mercenary army. When most of them got splattered, it brought the number up to a gore-friendly **17.**

**Jurassic Park III**
Truly disappointing in every way, including bodycount (**7**). Everyone knows it's supposed to go [up, not down](http://www.firstshowing.net/img/rambo-kill-chart.jpg?x10994).

**Jurassic World**
Doesn't disappoint. The increased budget seems to have inspired them to kill a lot more extras, resulting in a total death-count of **22.**

**Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom**
Bloodier than its predecessor. The body-count continues to climb and this installment sees another **24** dead, largely due to a scrumptious auction crowd.

**Jurassic World: Dominion**
A colossal **42**, if you include the 37 people killed off screen in "dino attacks this year". If you're only looking at on-screen deaths, the answer is that **only 5 people die in this film**, putting it in joint first place as 'least deadly' of the series.

---

### How Dangerous is Jurassic Park/World?

If we take Disneyland as a comparable attraction, in its 50+ year history, the total number of [directly attributable guest deaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidents_at_Disneyland_Resort#Disneyland_Park) is less than 10, including the resort's hotels and car parks. During that period, some 100,000,000 have visited the park and its environs, indicating a chance of dying during a visit to be around 0.00001%

Jurassic World was open for 10 years and has an average of 25000 visitors per day. Based on the number of guest deaths seen (22), the average chance of dying during a visit is around 0.000001%, making Jurassic World safer than Disneyland.

Comment: To recap all my comments that I have deleted. These "Carnage Count"  numbers are up for debate.

Comment: @Skooba - Yes, I've been through the "all the deaths" youtube video and recounted. I've also discounted any dino deaths and any deaths that aren't seen (or heard) on screen, however I've added a few for the boat crews since they were almost certainly 3-5 people, not one.

Comment: Tough, when I know you are still working on the answer and I am essentially watching your process.  FWIW, you have +1 from me

Comment: Getting "et"? Is that british slang? or a typo :)

Comment: @dvk-in-exile - Et is the past participle of eat. He was eaten, he got et. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/et

Comment: fwiw - Malcolm died in the first book as well, only to be brought back in the second book

Comment: @NKCampbell - I presume he was merely pretending to be dead to get sympathy

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lS9D6w1GzGY

Comment: "(and apparently delicious)", I snorted.  Thanks!

Comment: @Valorum you've only counted the on screen deaths.  It would be safe to assume that JP/JW has had a similar number of "normal" guest deaths over the years, probably about the same as Disneyland, ie another 10 or so.

Comment: 'At Disneyland the exhibits don't start eating the guests' (may have paraphrased a little)

Comment: Yeah, but, John, if The Pirates of the Caribbean breaks down, the pirates don't eat the tourists.” Fixed it.

Comment: 25000 visitors a day seems awfully high. But even taking that number, that gives 91 million visitors over 10 years, which is very comparable to the total for Disneyland. Given that 22 people (at least) died in Jurassic World as compared to 10 for Disneyland, this makes Jurassic World at least twice as dangerous.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez - You're comparing apples (staff and guest deaths) with oranges (guest deaths only). Also Disneyland gets an average of 100,000+ visitors per day on a normal day.

Comment: Your math is definitely a little off, and I can't really see any internal logic that would account for high JP numbers to skew the overall guest to death ratio.  On a slight side note, anyone else feel 25k a day would be unsustainable for an island base resort?  The lodging would need to be massive and I would think it would require a huge amount of ferrys and/or water taxis.

Comment: McFuu - The guest to death ratio is skewed heavily because we see lots of deaths in the films, but only two guest deaths.

Comment: And yes, 25,000 guests a day on a small island seems insane, but that's what the website says and we just need to accept it.

Comment: I don't think the deaths from *The Lost World* or *Jurassic Park III* should count, because they aren't park deaths.  The people in those movies went looking for trouble on islands with no park operations.

Comment: @tbrookside - I did think that. OP has specifically asked "*how many people have actually been killed or injured across the Jurassic Park/World franchise?*" as a sub-question though, which I took to mean as an out-of-universe bodycount for the films

Comment: @Valorum - Ah, you are right.  That's a better reading of the question than mine.

Comment: I've only used the in-park count for the Disneyland analysis though.