# What happened to the dinosaurs living on Isla Sorna?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

The newest movie in the Jurassic franchise deals with saving the dinosaurs living on Isla Nublar. However, from The Lost World and Jurassic Park 3 we know that Isla Sorna also had dinosaurs living there. Fallen Kingdom claims that if the dinosaurs on Nublar aren't saved - they will go extinct (again).

What does that mean for Sorna? Was the dino population of the island wiped out or captured when they built the Jurassic World on Nublar? Or something else entirely?

Comment: last I heard from Trevorrow, they were ignoring 2 & 3 and just making sequels to 1.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach according to this QA: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/133928/55735 they're still canon. Just not mentioned in World.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isla Sorna continued to function until Hurricane Clarissa hit the island. All personnel were evacuated from the island and the facilities were later abandoned. However, before they left, the InGen personnel unlocked the gates of the island's enclosures so that the dinosaurs could have a better chance of surviving the storm. Within a few years, the dinosaurs took over the island and established a fully functional ecosystem.

The island was finally de-populated in 2004 when all the animals were transferred to Isla Nublar.

However, things don't add up. It is said that:

> "The new species were grown in secret on Isla Sorna (Site B) and experimented on over a period of nine months, starting just 100 days after the company was bought by Masrani Global."

Only problem is Marsani bought InGen after John Hammond passed away in 1998, long after the hurricane had destroyed it (allegedly it hit Isla Sorna in 1993 right after the Isla Nublar incident).

And we also know from *Jurassic Park III* that in 2001 it was completely abandoned and restricted.

Check out the reports from the [Dinosaur Protection Group](http://www.dinosaurprotectiongroup.com/reports.html).

Answer (score 2):

Between the events of *The Lost World: Jurassic Park* and *Jurassic Park 3*, Masrani Global Corporation bought InGen and quickly began to secretly clone new dinosaurs on Isla Sorna, disrupting the ecosystem that had formed and resulting in many of the old dinosaurs dying. The surviving dinosaurs were captured and sent to Jurassic World on Isla Nublar.

> The new species were grown in secret on Isla Sorna (Site B) and experimented on over a period of nine months, starting just 100 days after the company was bought by Masrani Global.
>
> ---
>
> The operation to move the surviving animals from Isla Sorna to the park site on Isla Nublar was critical to their well-being. A considerable and mystifying drop in population on Isla Sorna had recently been discovered; some paleontologists claimed it was the result of territorial disputes, others argued disease was the catalyst, while some scientists even placed the blame on the animals’ behavior. Recent revelations linked to the corruption of the Gene Guard Act by members of Masrani Global confirm the true cause – the introduction of illegally cloned animals on the island in 1999 caused a profound impact on the ecosystem.

From [Source 1](http://www.dinosaurprotectiongroup.com/what-killed-the-gene-guard-act.html) and [Source 2](http://www.dinosaurprotectiongroup.com/the-rise-and-fall-of-masrani-global.html).

Answer (score -1):

I think that the dinosaurs on Site B (Isla Sorna) are flourishing.

Although there would be a few species gone extinct such as the Spinosaurus, possibly, due to their only being one Spino, not being able to reproduce without a counterpart (Unless it wanted to “bee” like Barry from the Bee Movie and hit it on with a different species of carnivore, which is unlikely).

The raptor’s second generation would have hatched by now and the original raptors might even be grandparents.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Here we are more of a Q/A site rather than a discussion forum so I have edited out the more "discussiony" parts of your answer. We also prefer answers backed with evidence rather than complete speculation, see the [tour]. So do you have any evidence for this answer you could [edit] in or is it just speculation?